# SQL sum hits per day and calculate percentage change

Tags: mysql, sql, union, percentage

I have a single table with a list of hits/downloads, every row has of course a date.
I was able to sum all the rows grouped by day.

Do you think it's possible to also calculate the change in percentage of every daily sum compared to the previous day using a single query, starting from the entire list of hits?

I tried to do this

```
select *, temp1.a-temp2.b/temp1.a*100 as percentage from
(select DATE(date), count(id_update) as a from vas_updates group by DATE(date)) as table1
 UNION
(select DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY), count(id_update) as b from vas_updates group by DATE(date)) as table2, vas_updates
```

but it won't work (100% CPU + crash).
Of course I can't JOIN them because those two temp tables share nothing in common being with 1 day offset.

The table looks like this, nothing fancy.

```
id_updates | date
1            2014-07-06 12:45:21
2            2014-07-06 12:46:10
3            2014-07-07 10:16:10
```

and I want

```
date       | sum a | sum b | percentage
2014-07-07   2       1       -50%
```

It can be either be positive or negative obviously

Comment: yes it is.  look up the LAG function.

Comment: Any way we could get a basic schema of your setup?  Furthermore, why the need of two temp tables?  @Randy brings a good point though.

Comment: What database are ou using?

Comment: Most probably `MySQL`. Guessing by the use of `INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select DATE(v.date), count(v.id_update) a, q2.b, count(v.id_update) - q2.b/count(v.id_update)*100 as Percentage
from vas_updates v
Left Join (select DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) d2, count(id_update) as b 
           from vas_updates group by d2) as q2
ON v.date = q2.d2
group by DATE(v.date)
```

Comment: I'm trying this one but I get a lot of unknown columns, maybe you need to set the alias "v" for one table? I tried but then I get "a" unknown!

Comment: I meant to set the alias to 'v' and I think the problem with 'a' was that I was using in the third column. I edited my answer now.

Comment: Hi, I suppose group by "d1" was supposed to be "d2"? Like this it takes 36 seconds and returns b and percentage all NULLs

Comment: I fixed that but as I said it doesn't return data and it takes 36 seconds.

Comment: does q2 on it's own work?
I had a similar query to this working on SQLite but it mysql has different functions for dates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56883/discussion-between-sandro-antonucci-and-germcd).

Answer (score 1):

The sum by day is:

```
select DATE(date), count(id_update) as a
from vas_update
group by DATE(date);
```

In MySQL, the easiest way to get the previous value is by using variables, which looks something like this:

```
select DATE(u.date), count(u.id_update) as cnt,
       @prevcnt as prevcnt, count(u.id_update) / @prevcnt * 100,
       @prevcnt := count(u.id_update)
from vas_update u cross join
     (select @prevcnt := 0) vars
group by DATE(u.date)
order by date(u.date);
```

This will generally work in practice, but MySQL doesn't guarantee the ordering of variables.  A more guaranteed approach looks like:

```
select dt, cnt, prevcnt, (case when prevcnt > 0 then 100 * cnt / prevcnt end)
from (select DATE(u.date) as dt, count(u.id_update) as cnt,
             (case when (@tmp := @prevcnt) is null then null
                   when (@prevcnt := count(u.id_update)) is null then null
                   else @tmp
              end) as prevcnt
      from vas_update u cross join
           (select @prevcnt := 0, @tmp := 0) vars
      group by DATE(u.date)
      order by date(u.date)
     ) t;
```

Comment: I get Unknown column 'prevcnt' in 'field list' for the last example

Comment: @SandroAntonucci . . . Typo.  I had left out a `@` in the second query.

Comment: Something is wrong, I get "0" for "prevcnt" and "NULL" for "100 * cnt / prevcnt"

Comment: @SandroAntonucci . . . That should happen for the first date.  The rest should have actual values.